# Stealing bits from an IEEE 754 double

Tags: c, floating-point, bit-manipulation

What are the effects on floating-point math likely to be if the least-significant bit(s) of the significand is(/are) set to a random value?

Explanation:

The language [PicoLisp](http://www.software-lab.de/doc/ref.html#cell) allocates *all* values using one structure, the cell, which consists of two "machine words". On a 32-bit system, this means a cell is an eight-byte structure of two 32-bit pointers or integers. Cells are aligned to their size, which means that at least the lowest three bits of a word are free to be used as type and GC tag data.

PicoLisp is very minimalist. One of the (many) things the language lacks is any support whatsoever for floating-point numbers, instead relying entirely on what the documentation calls "scaled fixpoint" representation. I thought it would be fun to try to add floating point support.

On 32-bit systems a 64-bit float will fit neatly inside one cell, conveniently meaning the allocation system can be pretty much the same, except for one minor problem: all 64 bits will be used by the double. But the GC expects to use bit 0 as a GC mark bit. Proceeding naively, bit 0 will be set to zero after every collection cycle regardless of what value was actually stored in the double.

(This is assuming the sizes and endianness all line up correctly. Assume for the purposes of this that they do; if they don't then the entire question is completely irrelevant and a different strategy necessarily has to be used.)

So: how much of a problem is this for general-purpose math, using the hardware float operations?

If all it does is reduce the precision of the double a tiny amount, then I figure that's not actually a problem: *as long as* it is documented that floating-point math in the interpreter isn't as precise as the user expects and they should fall back to fixpoint or a library or something if they need strictly accurate behaviour. My intuitive understanding of it is that this ought to be the case, since it's the least significant bit (doesn't even show up when you convert to a string..?).

On the other hand, floating point is, uh, witchcraft. Could this sort of bit-fiddling actually severely affect the usefulness of math or the ability to produce *any* kind of consistent results?

(I have considered several other implementation possibilities for the allocator. I'm specifically interested in whether *this* strategy is monumentally stupid or not, because it's the easiest and I am lazy.)

Comment: (1) This is a bad idea. (2) If garbage collection is using the low bit as a marker, won’t setting that bit to either zero or one by storing a `double` in the 64 bits interfere with garbage collection? Are you proposing to reduce the `double` to 63 bits in some fashion before storing or to let it interfere with garbage collection?

Comment: #2: I hadn't thought that through fully, but not if the system ensures by some means, either on operations or with a loop, that the bit is definitely zero before collection happens.

Comment: Have you considered just using single-precision `float` values that only consume half the cell? This would avoid all the nastiness.

Comment: I had, and there should be an option for that, but with doubles I could more reasonably replace the existing integer type altogether. The range of single-precision floats is a little limited for that.

Comment: *". . . instead relying entirely on what the documentation calls 'scaled fixpoint' representation."* Actually, [the docs](http://software-lab.de/doc/faq.html#floats) call it "scaled fixpoint numbers, with *unlimited* precision." (Emphasis added.) Also, there are three floating-point alternatives: "native", in-line C, and the math.l lib. Speaking only for myself, I've reached an age where bit-twiddling is no longer attractive. What kind of progress have you made on this during the past year and a half?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I eventually worked out an alternative strategy involving segmenting the Lisp heap (that can also be used for a bunch of other things). Not all memory areas are tagged or scanned the same way, but this is transparent to `car` & friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as outside code always sees the value as if the low bit has been rounded off, and you do this by rounding the mantissa to the nearest even value, for normal calculations that would be okay.

That is, for mantissas that end in:

`00`: do nothing

`10`: do nothing

`01`: subtract 1 from the mantissa

`11`: add 1 to the mantissa (on overflow, you will need to increment the exponent and clear the mantissa)

If you aren't consistent with your rounding and just lop off the low bit, you will introduce a very slight downward bias to your calculations. Rounding towards even is IEEE's way of counteracting that downward bias.

Be careful with +/- infinity, as setting the low bit will turn those into NANs, which are pretty brittle to work with (suddenly all your comparison ops start failing).

Comment: This answer appears to be proposing a scheme in which a 64-bit `double` is reduced to 63 bits before storage, to keep its low bit available for garbage collection purposes. It would be clearer if the answer explained that. In addition to the accuracy issues, this can introduce problems with code that uses the significands of NaNs to carry information.

Comment: Reducing accuracy even by one bit involves an actual rounding operation... yeah I'm starting to see a lot more of the problems with my idea now.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: indeed, but I thought "store a double in 63 bits" would be fairly well understood by anyone reading the OP's question? He wants to reuse the low bit for his own GC purposes; you would have to come into my answer with that understanding already. I'm just explaining how to do that safely. Also, you're right that if someone is storing data in NaN mantissas, the GC would be corrupting that data's low bit, but that's an extremely rare use case--most people don't know enough about IEEE-754 to do such a thing, and I don't think that'd even be possible in PicoLisp anyway.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: I do not find the text “store a double in 63 bits” anywhere else in this question and its answers, so I do not see how a phrase that is not present could have been understood. What was contemplated is not clear because there are multiple options: Truncate a double by clearing the low bit, convert a double to 63 bits by rounding, perform arithmetic in 63-bit floating-point so there is no 64th bit, store all 64 bits and let garbage collection alter the low bit, and perhaps others.

Comment: Your concerns are duly noted.

Comment: Truncating to 63-bit a `double` computed as 64-bit will cause **double rounding** for many operations. The arithmetic will not longer possess the properties of IEEE 754. Algorithms that were designed for systems with these properties will not downgrade gracefully to have one fewer bit of precision but fail completely.

Comment: I can't argue with that. If OP's PicoLisp code uses algorithms that need all 64 bits of precision to succeed, this approach cannot work. It's only amenable to code which will respond well to a slight amount of rounding error. Do note, however, that I am not recommending truncation, but rather round-to-even as IEEE-754 would itself do.

Comment: @Pascal: Don't forget, the standard double-precision arithmetic mode used by many (most?) Intel compilers computes intermediate results in internal 8-bit registers, and stores them as 64 bits only when necessary. Conceptually, this is exactly the same as Stiles' suggestion. It generally works very well, although it sometimes causes programmers to scratch their heads. It certainly doesn't have a tendency to "fail completely".

Comment: @TonyK The only way this comment would make sense is by substituting “80-bit” where these is “8-bit”, so I will do just that. Computing in 80-bit registers and rounding to 64-bit causes double rounding in rare cases, but not rare enough for people not to complain loudly about it and develop strange superstitions of floating-point being non-deterministic and unreliable. Computing with 64-bit and then rounding to 63-bit causes double rounding in **many** cases.

Comment: @TonyK The C function on this page computes the conversion to integer of a floating-point number if executed with strict IEEE 754 semantics. If computations are made with excess precision, it “fails completely”: it loops forever or return a result that may have no relation to what is supposed to be computed. http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/01/A-conversionless-conversion-function2 There are plenty of other examples, some of them more useful than this.

Comment: @Pascal: it's worth noting that the program you show already fails in many compilers' default settings as it is not compatible with SSE math either--it demands execution on the x87 alone. This is not, IMO, a convincing argument.

Comment: @StilesCrisis No, the program I show demands execution on a platform that implements IEEE 754. It does not demand execution on the x87. It fails on the x87.

Answer (score 2):

The scheme StilesCrisis is proposing causes **double rounding**, which is generally considered a [bad thing](http://www.exploringbinary.com/double-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-conversions/).

One other option I would like to suggest:

Display and compute with each PicoLisp float as if it was 2<sup>512</sup> times larger than it it. This means double addition and subtraction remain almost unchanged, multiplication and division require one cheap adjustment, and other operations (library calls) require two adjustments, one before and one after.

After each operation, check for overflow (which now happens more often, every time the biased result is above 1.0).

If you do this, instead of borrowing the least significant bit of the significand, you are actually borrowing the most significant bit of the exponent. This requires some bit-shuffling to load and store floats but this will be much easier to explain to programmers using the system, and algorithms designed for IEEE 754-like properties will continue to work (except when they now overflow).

---

The code might look like this [lightly tested implementation](http://ideone.com/f81Xqo). A similar implementation in another context is the object of this [blog post](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/09/A-63-bit-floating-point-type-for-64-bit-OCaml), that provides more explanation.

```
void smalldouble_to_cell(void*p, double d)
{
  union u u;
  u.d = d;
  unsigned long long rest = u.u & 0x7fffffffffffffff;
  unsigned long long packed;
  if (rest > 0x7ff0000000000000)
    /* NaN */
    packed = u.u & 0xfffffffffffffffe;
  else 
    {
      unsigned long long sign = u.u & 0x8000000000000000;
      if (rest >= 0x3ff0000000000000)
    rest = 0x3ff0000000000000;
      packed = sign | (rest << 1);
    }
  memcpy(p, &packed, 8);
}

void double_to_cell(void *p, double d)
{
  smalldouble_to_cell(p, ldexp(d, -512));
}
```

Comment: When you say "2^10 times larger," what do you mean exactly? I get stealing an exponent bit in a binary sense, but adding or multiplying by 1024 doesn't seem to accomplish that.

Comment: @StilesCrisis That should be 2^512, probably. The problem is that IEEE 754 mandates that operations produce denormals for very small results. Trying to emulate reduced-range denormals from full-range computations result in double rounding (again! Actually this is one of the problems known to people who have been trying to emulate IEEE 754 from x87 instructions). So the idea is: since hardware instructions compute with exponents between -1023 and 1022, instead of limiting ourselves to the half this range around zero, why not use the bottom half and let the hardware handle denormals directly?

Comment: @StilesCrisis But programmers will want to use numbers both higher and lower than one, not just below that one, so when they write 1.0, store it as 2^-512. If they add two numbers, add. If they multiply, scale one operand up by 2^512 and multiply…

Comment: You didn't actually answer my question.

Comment: When you say "2^10 (512?) times larger," what do you mean exactly? Present an actual mathematical operation.

Comment: but as the OP said, "the GC expects to use bit 0 as a GC mark bit" so the bit will be round off anyway

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Behold the magic of `|` (magic bitwise or) and `<<` (magic bitwise shift): http://ideone.com/f81Xqo (PS: the link was in the answer already)

Answer (score 1):

A change in the least significant bit of the significand normally has exactly the effect you think it has — it'll change the least significant recorded bit of the number.

However you'll hit problems with some of the special cases.

[EDITED as per Eric Postpischil's accurate criticism of my previous text here: adjusting a zero representation will simply result in a very small denormal number]

You'll see something like the opposite problem with encodings of plus or minus infinity. Inifinity is encoded with the largest possible exponent and a zero significand. If the significand is modified then infinite will turn into NaN.

Comment: Setting a bit in the significand does not affect the implicit bit. The implicit bit is entirely determined by the exponent: An exponent field of all zeroes indicates a subnormal value or zero, both of which have an implicit bit of zero. An exponent field of all ones indicates infinity or a NaN. Any other exponent field indicates a normal value, which has an implicit bit of one.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it cites setting to zero as an example but the question is "What are the effects on floating-point math likely to be if the least-significant bit(s) of the significand is(/are) set to a random value?"; you're absolutely right about denormal numbers.

Comment: Thanks. So as per both answers and the comments, breaking float semantics seems like the main problem here rather than accuracy.